# Checking isset on session stops javascript

Tags: javascript, php, session

Hey I am checking if for existence of $_SESSION variable from javascript..

```
         if (<?php echo isset($_SESSION["variable"]); ?>){
             //alert ("lol");

         }
```

if it exists it works fine, otherwise it gives java script error. 
For example

```
alert("<?php echo isset($_SESSION["variable"]); ?>");
```

gives empty alert, but it doesn't give errors

What am i missing?

Comment: Well the difference would be that your second statement has quotes around the interpolated php blob, but the first doesn't. Have you checked for errors in the console for the first piece of code?

Comment: Also, that's kind-of a goofy way to generate the code. It'd be better to just do an `if` statement in PHP and only generate an alert if the session variable is present.

Comment: Hmm yeah thnx. fixed it. My NetBeans doesn't give javascript errors so im kinda in the dark ://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` won't output `false` so you are getting `if()` which is a syntax error. You could use `var_export(isset($_SESSION['variable']))` instead, it will either output `true` or `false`

Comment: got it working             if (!"<?php echo isset($_SESSION["variable"]); ?>"){
             alert ("lol");
             
            }

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the following as isset($_SESSION["variable"]) doesn't result in a string you can echo

```
alert("<?php echo isset($_SESSION["variable"])?"lol":""; ?>");
```

or

```
alert("<?= isset($_SESSION["variable"])?"lol":""; ?>");
```

Comment: that alert was just to check if the statement works xD. thxn still for answer

Comment: Yeah it was already answered in another way too - probably should have thrown it on a comment.  But, it's a briefer way of outputting it for debugging.